# Magento - Change compare button to facebook like button

Tags: magento, button, compare, magento-1.7

I want to change the compare button with facebook like button in addto button/link located along with addto wishlist add to cart links/buttons.

```
/app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml
```

I want to change in both category as well as product view.

Here is the code of addto.phtml

```
 ?>

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_wishlistSubmitUrl = $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>

<ul class="add-to-links">
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
    <li><a rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
    $_compareUrl = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product);
?>
<?php if($_compareUrl) : ?>
    <li><a rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_wishlistSubmitUrl = $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>

<ul class="add-to-links">
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
    <li><a rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
    <li>
        <!-- put fb code here eg -->
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fmageigniter.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </li>
</ul>
```